# grabbing value of select in table column with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to grab a value of a select based if i click on a button. Here's my code.

```
<tr>
  <td width="50%"><a href="clients_detail.asp?clientID=470">ABC Corp</a></td>
  <td width="50%">
    <select id="salesPersonID" name="salesPersonID" class="form-control">
      <option value="" 0""="">Select Contact</option>
      <option value="424">Aaron  Fick</option>
      <option value="492">John Smith</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:center;"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info but_save" data-clientid="470" data-column="salesPersonID" data-carrierid="0">save</button>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="50%"><a href="clients_detail.asp?clientID=471">CDEF Corp</a></td>
  <td width="50%">
    <select id="salesPersonID" name="salesPersonID" class="form-control">
      <option value="" 0""="">Select Contact</option>
      <option value="424">Aaron  Fick</option>
      <option value="492">John Smith</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:center;"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info but_save" data-clientid="470" data-column="salesPersonID" data-carrierid="0">save</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

If the button on the 2nd row is clicked i want to grab the value of the select box that is right above it. here's the code i'm using but can't seem to get it right:

```
$(document).on('click','.but_save',function(){

    var value = $(this).closest('td.select').val();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$(this).parent().prev('td').find('select').val()`

`$(this)` gets the `<button>`

`.parent()` gets to the button's `<td>`

`.prev('td')` gets the previous element that is a `<td>`

`.find('select')` gets the select inside the `<td>`

```js
$(document).on('click','.but_save',function(){
  var value = $(this).parent().prev('td').find('select').css('border','1px solid red').val();
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td width="50%"><a href="clients_detail.asp?clientID=470">ABC Corp</a></td>
  <td width="50%">
    <select id="salesPersonID" name="salesPersonID" class="form-control">
      <option value="" 0""="">Select Contact</option>
      <option value="424">Aaron  Fick</option>
      <option value="492">John Smith</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:center;"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info but_save" data-clientid="470" data-column="salesPersonID" data-carrierid="0">save</button>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="50%"><a href="clients_detail.asp?clientID=471">CDEF Corp</a></td>
  <td width="50%">
    <select id="salesPersonID" name="salesPersonID" class="form-control">
      <option value="" 0""="">Select Contact</option>
      <option value="424">Aaron  Fick</option>
      <option value="492">John Smith</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:center;"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info but_save" data-clientid="470" data-column="salesPersonID" data-carrierid="0">save</button>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Love this answer. Thanks for breaking it down for me like that!

Answer (score 0):

The line `$(this).closest('td.select')` looks for an element that looks like

```
<td class="select"></td>
```

and as a TD has no value, that won't work...
Also, the closest TD has no `<select>` element, that would be another TD inside the same TR, so you probably wanted

```
var value = $(this).closest('tr').find('select').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following -

```js
$('.but_save').click(function() {
  var value = $(this).parent().prev().find('select').val();
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="50%"><a href="clients_detail.asp?clientID=470">ABC Corp</a>
    </td>
    <td width="50%">
      <select id="salesPersonID" name="salesPersonID" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">Select Contact</option>
        <option value="424">Aaron Fick</option>
        <option value="492">John Smith</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info but_save" data-clientid="470" data-column="salesPersonID" data-carrierid="0">save</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50%"><a href="clients_detail.asp?clientID=471">CDEF Corp</a>
    </td>
    <td width="50%">
      <select id="salesPersonID" name="salesPersonID" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">Select Contact</option>
        <option value="424">Aaron Fick</option>
        <option value="492">John Smith</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info but_save" data-clientid="470" data-column="salesPersonID" data-carrierid="0">save</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```